# Custom bitbake bbapend not correctly appending mender fstab file

Tags: linux, sed, embedded, yocto, bitbake

I'm using github.com/mendersoftware/meta-mender in my yocto build. I want to edit /etc/fstab using `sed` with a bbappend file in my own layer. Specifically, meta-mender is currently supplying their own fstab file and editing it with a `base-files_3.%.bbappend`, and I just want to remove the `auto` keyword from the generated /etc/fstab.

The problem is that when I supply my own bbappend (my layer has a higher priority than meta-mender) in my layer for base-files_3.%.bbappend, the meta-mender fstab doesn't seem to be created at all, and the stock one from open-embedded is instead.

Here is my meta-layer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.%.bbappend:

```
do_install_append(){
    sed -i -e 's$.*@MENDER_BOOT_PART@.*$@MENDER_BOOT_PART@   /uboot           @MENDER_BOOT_PART_FSTYPE@       defaults,sync    0  0$' ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab
    sed -i -e 's$.*@MENDER_DATA_PART@.*$@MENDER_DATA_PART@   /data     @MENDER_DATA_PART_FSTYPE@       defaults         0  0$' ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab
}
```

If I run `bitbake -e base-files`, then look for the do_install function, you can clearly see that my `sed` commands are correctly being appended to meta-mender/meta-mender-core/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3:

```
do_install() {
for d in /boot /dev /bin /sbin /lib            /etc /etc/default            /etc/skel /lib /mnt /proc /home/root /run            /usr /usr/bin /usr/share/doc/base-files-3.0.14 /usr/games /usr/include            /usr/lib /usr/sbin /usr/share            /usr/share/common-licenses /usr/share/dict /usr/share/info            /usr/share/man /usr/share/misc /var            /var/backups /var/lib            /sys /var/lib/misc /var/spool            /var/volatile            /var/volatile/log            /home /usr/src /var/local            /media; do
    install -m 0755 -d /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image$d
done
for d in /tmp /var/volatile/tmp; do
    install -m 1777 -d /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image$d
done
for d in ; do
    install -m 2775 -d /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image$d
done
for d in log tmp; do
    ln -sf volatile/$d /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/var/$d
done

ln -snf ../run /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/var/run
ln -snf ../run/lock /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/var/lock

do_install_basefilesissue

rotation=`cat /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/rotation`
if [ "$rotation" != "0" ]; then
    install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/rotation /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/rotation
fi

install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/fstab /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/fstab
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/filesystems /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/filesystems
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/usbd /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/default/usbd
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/profile /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/profile
sed -i 's#ROOTHOME#/home/root#' /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/profile
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/shells /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/shells
install -m 0755 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/share/dot.profile /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/skel/.profile
install -m 0755 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/share/dot.bashrc /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/skel/.bashrc
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/nsswitch.conf /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/nsswitch.conf
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/host.conf /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/host.conf
install -m 0644 /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/motd /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/motd

ln -sf /proc/mounts /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/mtab
install -d /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/uboot
install -d /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/data
sed -i -e 's$.*@MENDER_BOOT_PART@.*$@MENDER_BOOT_PART@   /uboot               @MENDER_BOOT_PART_FSTYPE@       defaults,sync    0  0$' /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/fstab
sed -i -e 's$.*@MENDER_DATA_PART@.*$@MENDER_DATA_PART@   /data                @MENDER_DATA_PART_FSTYPE@       defaults         0  0$' /home/user/Desktop/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/base-files/3.0.14-r89/image/etc/fstab
```

}

And  yet, my /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
# stock fstab - you probably want to override this with a machine specific one

/dev/root            /                    auto       defaults              1  1
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0  0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0  0
tmpfs                /run                 tmpfs      
mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0  0
tmpfs                /var/volatile        tmpfs      defaults              0  0

# uncomment this if your device has a SD/MMC/Transflash slot
#/dev/mmcblk0p1       /media/card          auto       defaults,sync,noauto  0  0
```

As you can see, it's completely skipping meta-menders' /etc/fstab file and just writing a stock one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what does `.*@MENDER_BOOT_PART@.*` in your sed-expression evaluate to?

As far as I can see, you don't have anything matching either one of `.*@MENDER_BOOT_PART@.*` nor`.*@MENDER_DATA_PART@.*` in you fstab.

If my understanding is correct, you could just as use something similar to

```
 echo "data" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab
```